# How do I use the "call transaction 'se11' and skip first screen" to activate the search box in ABAP?

Tags: abap

What I am trying to do is use

```
Set Parameter ID 'DTB' Field 'z*'.
Call Transaction 'SE11' and skip First Screen.
```

At this point I want to activate the search box and take the results into an internal table. Any thoughts? Or is there a way to use the data base statistics to pull this information faster?

Comment: Please describe the desired outcome, not only your failed attempt. It's hard to propose a correct solution if we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to get all z tables from the report into an internal table. I mainly need to know if there is a way to activate the search box in the program code and pull the following report into a table. 

In sort I need a table that I can use that contains all the custom table without doing a full database scan.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark one of the answers as 'correct' using the green check mark if it helped you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing the tables directly, you may want to use a semi-official API that not only handles the activation state, but also takes permissions into account as well:

```
  DATA: lt_tables TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF rpy_tabl.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_table> TYPE rpy_tabl.

  CALL FUNCTION 'RPY_TABLE_SELECT'
    EXPORTING
      table_name       = 'Z*'
    TABLES
      tabl_inf_tab     = lt_tables
    EXCEPTIONS
      cancelled        = 1
      not_found        = 2
      permission_error = 3
      OTHERS           = 4.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
*   Implement suitable error handling here
  ELSE.

    LOOP AT lt_tables ASSIGNING <ls_table>.
      CASE <ls_table>-tablclass.
        WHEN 'TRANSP'.  " Transparent table
*         ...
        WHEN 'INTTAB'.  " Structure
*         ...
        WHEN 'CLUSTER'. " Cluster table
*         ...
        WHEN 'POOL'.    " Pooled table
*         ...
        WHEN 'VIEW'.    " Generated view structure
*         ...
        WHEN 'APPEND'.  " Append structure
*         ...
      ENDCASE.
    ENDLOOP.

  ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get what you want, you might need to add some more where clauses to only get active tables (AS4LOCAL EQ 'A')or only transparent tables (TABCLASS EQ 'TRANSP') since this table also contains structures.

```
DATA: t_tabname TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tabname.
SELECT tabname INTO TABLE t_tabname FROM dd02l WHERE tabname LIKE 'Z%'.
```